# Labeled LDA inference in Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, lda

I am using Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox v.0.3 for doing LabeledLDA.
I was able to train a LabeledLDA model using the [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/) ([example-6-llda-learn.scala](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/examples/example-6-llda-learn.scala)) provided.
How can I predict labels for a new dataset?

I tried using code similar to [example-3-lda-infer.scala](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/examples/example-3-lda-infer.scala) for the inference on new dataset but it was not successful. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

*Edit*
This is the code I use for inference but it is not working:

```
// tells Scala where to find the TMT classes
import scalanlp.io._;
import scalanlp.stage._;
import scalanlp.stage.text._;
import scalanlp.text.tokenize._;
import scalanlp.pipes.Pipes.global._;

import edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.stage._;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.lda._;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda._;

// the path of the model to load
val modelPath = file("llda-cvb0-2053ec3f-13-a69e079a-5cd58962");

//Labeled LDA model

println("Loading "+modelPath);
val model = LoadCVB0LabeledLDA(modelPath);
// Or, for a Gibbs model, use:
// val model = LoadGibbsLDA(modelPath);

// A new dataset for inference.  (Here we use the same dataset
// that we trained against, but this file could be something new.)
val source = CSVFile("test_lab_lda.csv") ~> IDColumn(1);
// Test File

val text = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(2) ~>                           // select column containing text
  TokenizeWith(model.tokenizer.get)      // tokenize with existing model's tokenizer
}

// Base name of output files to generate
val output = file(modelPath, source.meta[java.io.File].getName.replaceAll(".csv",""));

// turn the text into a dataset ready to be used with LDA
val dataset = LabeledLDADataset(text);

val out_val=InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions(model, dataset)
CSVFile(output+"-document-topic-distributuions.csv").write(out_val);
```

This code upon execution as `java -Xmx3g -jar tmt-0.3.3.jar infer_llda.scala` produces following error:

```
infer_llda.scala:40: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (name: String,terms: Iterable[Iterable[String]],labels: Iterable[Iterable[String]],termIndex: Option[scalanlp.util.Index[String]],labelIndex: Option[scalanlp.util.Index[String]],tokenizer: Option[scalanlp.text.tokenize.Tokenizer])edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda.LabeledLDADataset[((Iterable[String], Iterable[String]), Int)] <and>
  [ID(in method apply)](text: scalanlp.stage.Parcel[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[scalanlp.stage.Item[ID(in method apply),Iterable[String]]]],labels: scalanlp.stage.Parcel[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[scalanlp.stage.Item[ID(in method apply),Iterable[String]]]],termIndex: Option[scalanlp.util.Index[String]],labelIndex: Option[scalanlp.util.Index[String]])edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda.LabeledLDADataset[(ID(in method apply), Iterable[String], Iterable[String])] <and>
  [ID(in method apply)](text: scalanlp.stage.Parcel[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[scalanlp.stage.Item[ID(in method apply),Iterable[String]]]],labels: scalanlp.stage.Parcel[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[scalanlp.stage.Item[ID(in method apply),Iterable[String]]]])edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda.LabeledLDADataset[(ID(in method apply), Iterable[String], Iterable[String])]
 cannot be applied to (scalanlp.stage.Parcel[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[scalanlp.stage.Item[String,Iterable[String]]]])
val dataset = LabeledLDADataset(text);
              ^
infer_llda.scala:43: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalanlp.serialization.TableWritable[scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[(String, scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray[Double])]]
CSVFile(output+"-document-topic-distributuions.csv").write(out_val);
```

With help from @Skarab here is the solution to Labeled LDA learning and inference:

- [Learning](https://gist.github.com/1122784)
- [Inference](https://gist.github.com/1122788)

Comment: Could you provide a code sample? It would be easier to help you seeing your code.

Comment: I have added the inference code now.

Comment: What does it mean: "not successful"? Did you get an error?

Comment: Added the error which is what I mean as unsuccessful.

Comment: I had exactly the same error, did you try stanford nlp mailing list: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#Mail ?

Comment: Ya I tried it mailing the question to the list but have not received any reply as of now http://bit.ly/qLdSWD

Comment: To get rid of the first error message (how to correctly create LabeledLDADataset), take a look on this example - http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/examples/llda-infer.scala . However I keep getting the second error message.

Comment: Thanks Skarab, I got it up and running. will put the code in a pastebin or github gist soon.

Comment: @Skarab: Here are the links to the code which I used to http://bit.ly/ocK2T9 (learning) and  http://bit.ly/qIWb6C (inference) please let me know if you still encounter any errors.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to put the links to your code as an answer so if other people can easily find the solution.